# Read Usenet comp.unix and more with back-then software (trn)

Tags: usenet

Is there a way to read the comp.unix Usenet discussions (and others) using the software that was used then? I'd like to read it to learn, but I can do a bit of escapism at the same time. Besides, as Usenet was so immense in popularity, probably that software wasn't bad at all. I found `trn` ("threaded read news program"), and, with `export NNTPSERVER=Aioe.org`, I get something, but not anything sensible to read. It seems, you should put newsgroups in a `.newsrc` file. Does anyone know how to do this if it is indeed possible?

Comment: Emacs gnus perhaps?

Comment: @jordanm: Yes, do you know how to set that up to get, for example, comp.unix threads from the 90's (my favorite decade)? That would be so cool! I don't know anything about Usenet because it was never within my radar as a kid; now, I read the Wikipedia article but it was mostly architecture and politics (which, of course, is interesting, but not what I seek).

Comment: Note that most news reader applications include a header that identifies the software being used in each article they post (User-Agent or X-Mailer). So, if you want to know what reader is popular in a particular newsgroup, just look at the headers of the messages there. In the comp.unix hierarchy, slrn and gnus are quite popular. I use a patched version of mutt with NNTP support. Note that usenet is far from being dead (despite google's sabotage) and has been going on for over 30 years (predates the web).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most Unix-based newsreaders, you need a `$HOME/.newsrc` file. It tracks (by article number) which articles you've already read in each newsgroup.

`.newsrc` is a plain text file. To start with, you can just created it with the name of each newsgroup you want to read on a line by itself, with a `:` appended to it.

I don't believe `comp.unix` still exists, but there are a number of newsgroups in the `comp.unix.*` hierarchy.

For example:

```
comp.unix.misc:
comp.unix.programmer:
comp.unix.shell:
```

Newsreaders (such as `trn` will generally have ways to get a list of all newsgroups and to subscribe and unsubscribe to newsgroups; you might not need to edit `.newsrc` manually (but you might as well, at least initially).

[aoie.org](http://aioe.org/) is one free NNTP server -- but as I understand it it's fairly heavily used by spammers, and some Usenet participants ignore articles posted from there. I use [eternal-september.org](http://news.eternal-september.org/) myself. You have to set up a free account and create a `$HOME/.authinfo` file; see their web page for more information.

A number of Usenet newsgroups are still quite active. (I hang out in comp.lang.c myself.) Servers other than groups.google.com don't save articles for more than a few months. Google doesn't provide an NNTP interface -- and its web interface has some serious problems.

My own preferred Usenet client program is [Gnus](http://gnus.org/), which runs under emacs; you'll probably like Gnus if and only if you like emacs.

Comment: Yes, `export NNTPSERVER=Aioe.org` in `.zshrc`, then the three newsgroups you suggested in `.newsrc`, then `M-x gnus` in Emacs, that's all there is to it. (I'll try the other server later: Aioe.org seems to work at first glance, though.)