# how to read news using rn command

Tags: ubuntu

Please am just learning Unix. Am interested in reading news on the terminal. I did some research, and I found out one of the command you need is `rn`. I typed `rn` on my command line, and I was asked to install `trn`, which I have done.

I typed `rn` on the command prompt. I was told welcome to `trn` 3.6 and some other stuff (which because am still new to Unix, I would have copied and pasted here, but can't, don't know how). I was then prompted to type space to continue, which I did.

Then I got these message:

```
connection to ###.#.#.#(a number): connection refused
giving up...
News server myusername-VirtualBox unavailable, try again later
```

Please can someone be of help. Am using Ubuntu 16.04LTS on VirtualBox(oracle)

Comment: You probably want to get a book that's been more recently than 20-25 years ago. Usenet does still exist but it's hidden in the backwaters of the Internet. There are much better readers than `rn` or even `trn`. If you want a text reader try `tin`. But you'll still need a working nntp feed

Comment: @roaima Cheers Mate Please can you recommend a good recent book on unix

Comment: @kusalananda Cheers mate.

Comment: @Evan Unfortunately, requests for learning material is off-topic in this forum, and I don't know any recent books on Unix that covers Usenet News.

Comment: Please can anyone recommend a good recent book on unix philosophy. At the moment, I've got the unix programming environment book by Kernighan & Pike. A great book, but I think it's old. Cheers Guys

Comment: Related: [Read Usenet comp.unix and more with back-then software](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56173/read-usenet-comp-unix-and-more-with-back-then-software-trn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the books on the history of Unix and Linx won't hurt.  But as mentioned, the commands (for reading news and groups you are looking at are ancient.  They were popular and important when most people used a console terminal interface for everything.  You would likely get better mileage by using a graphic (web) interface for your studies, news, and groups.  [Wikipedia](http://wikipedia.org) has lots of information on the historic development and stages.

The tone of your message sounds like you might be interested in learning Unix.  If that is the case, you can use a resource such as [Tutorialpoint's Unix Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/), which will also provide some history of Unix along with an outline of the various commands and usage.  Becoming familiar with some of these details may fill in some of the gaps you are having in trying to understand the ancient news readers that you are exploring.

There are many applications for reading newsgroup.  Thunderbird has a newsgroup reader feature (http://www.fastusenet.org/thunderbird-tutorial.html).

Usenet probably appeared to be free to most people who were using it back in the day.  However, they were using a service of their ISP who was linked as a Usenet feed (server).  To be effective, the server host a huge amount of data.  I haven't checked lately, but I'm sure it's not as common these days for most ISP's to invest in the resources.

There are a number of Usenet providers.  Most of them charge a fee and provide readers and search engines for their clients.  This is an example list: https://usenetreviewz.com/best-usenet-providers/

Google became a popular free Usenet provider.  They eventually started calling the groups on their server, Google Groups.  With time the regular Usenet groups on the google server became somewhat hidden, and you mainly just see the Google groups of the feeds.  If you look close enough you can find the other Usenet groups.  However, their reader interface has lost the ease of use of the regular Usenet groups (outside of their own groups).

In more direct reference to your question concerning reading the groups with rn, tin, trn, you would have to first locate the server you want to use and configure the text-based client for that server.

Your message is indicating that your server isn't configured.  You can test it out with some of the newsfeeds in the list above.  If you sign up for one of the fee base newsfeeds, they will provide you with a client for accessing.  You'll then be able to compare the access information they provide you with for the information in your **trn** client files.  This will get you past the **connection refused** and **server unavailable** error messages.

Comment: Cheers mate. I appreciate